# Pandas: a faster way to use groupby then shift?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DF as follows:

| index | date_block_num | shop_id | item_id | item_price | item_cnt_month | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 2 | 33 | 499.0 | 1.0 | 05.01.2013 |
| 1 | 0 | 2 | 491 | 600.0 | 1.0 | 09.01.2013 |
| 2 | 0 | 2 | 1007 | 449.0 | 3.0 | 11.01.2013 |
| 3 | 0 | 2 | 1010 | 449.0 | 1.0 | 21.01.2013 |
| 4 | 0 | 2 | 1023 | 299.0 | 2.0 | 06.01.2013 |

I want to create lagged features using `shift()`.

I tried: `df["last_1_month_sales"] = df.groupby(["date_block_num", "shop_id", "item_id"])["item_cnt_month"].shift(periods = 1, fill_value=0)`. However, since the DF is big (~800k rows), the Groupby function takes a very long time. Is there a better alternative way to speed up this process?

I can convert it to `cudf DataFrame` for faster groupby, but it does not support `shift()` function, nor support converting the cudf Groupby object back to Pandas object.

Comment: That isn't a very big dataframe, how long is this taking exactly?

Comment: About 1-2 minutes, but it takes like 80-90% of my feature engineering process I want to speed it up a bit.

Answer (score 1):

The cudf github repo has a [feature request open](https://github.com/rapidsai/cudf/issues/7183) to implement the `shift` function with groupby

While the amazing cuDF team is working on this you can use the cudf GroupBy `apply` function to use the `shift` operation after groupby.
Example code:

```
import pandas as pd
import dask.dataframe as dd
import cudf
# Create the dataframe
pdf = pd.DataFrame({
    "a": [0,1,0,1,1,0],
    "b": range(6),
    "c": ["a","b","c","d","e","f"]
})
gdf = cudf.from_pandas(pdf)

# Custom apply function
def grp_shift(df):
    df["d"] = df.b.shift(1)
    return df


print("pandas shift function : ")
print(pdf.groupby("a").b.shift(1))

print("cudfs shift function : ")
print(gdf.groupby("a").apply(grp_shift).d)
```